# Unknown input byte length convert to int

Tags: java, android, string, arduino

My android program need to receive int values from arduino analog sensor via usb and print them on real time graph, i  receive `byte[]`  from call back function.

i tried many ways to convert from `byte[]` to string or int include `new String` `new Integer` `BigInteger` `parseInt` and some code method that i find in other topics, but nothing work i receive only half of the correct values, other values to much bugger or smaller.

The byte[] length changed from 1 to 4 , their is some empty bytes, it look like this(log):

[image]

How i can to convert it to correct values? where the problem?

In ideal i need  receive int values between 230 to 300 from sensor.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your sensor is using text protocol. If I convert your bytes to ASCII chars, it will be:

```
..
10-LF
50-2
53-5
56-8
..
13-CR
10-LF
50-2
53-5
..
54-6
13-CR
10-LF
etc.
```

Interpreted as

```
258
256
```

so, I thing the best solution is to accumulate received bytes as chars and when CRLF is reveived, read whole string (with stripped CRLF) as int - probably via parseInt.

Answer (score 0):

Arduino code segment?
Guessing badly : int is a 16 bit value byte is 8 bits.
Int_8 is -128 to 127 . uint8_t 0-255 not supported by java as far as i know but you can use the char type unsigned 16 bit(need to cast it).